# setup a cron expression from 7.30 to 18.30 every 10 mn with one born included

Tags: cron, cronexpression

Is it possible to write one expression in order to have this behavior:

- fire at 7.30 every 10 mn until 18.30
  result : 7.40, 7.50, 8.00, 8.10 ........ 18.10, 18.20, 18.30

Answer (score 0):

Three entries-:

```
 0,10,20,30,40,50 8-17 * * * command
 30,40,50 7 * * * command
 0,10,20,30 18 * * * command
```